# signed and unsigned fixed point multiplication in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, multiplication, unsigned, signed

I have a specific question and a request for more general guidance.

My question is what is the cleanest way to multiply a signed number by an unsigned number in SystemVerilog?

Below is a little test code that illustrates the problem. 'a' is the unsigned number. 'b' is the signed number. In order to produce a correct signed result SystemVerilog seems to require that both operands of the multiplication be signed. To make that work here I had to add an extra '0' to the front of the unsigned number to make it a valid signed number.  I'm thinking there must be a cleaner way.

More generally, I am just getting started doing fixed point math in SystemVerilog. In VHDL there is very concrete syntax and even a standard package to support signed and unsigned fixed point math, with rounding, etc.  Is there something like that in the SystemVerilog world?

Thanks,

```
module testbench ();
    localparam int Wa = 8;
    localparam int Wb = 8;

    logic  [Wa-1:0] a;       // unsigned
    logic  [Wa:0] a_signed;  // signed word with extra bit to hold unsigned number.
    logic  [Wb-1:0] b;       // signed
    logic  [Wa+Wb-1:0] c;    // result

    localparam clk_period = 10;

    assign a_signed = {1'b0, a};
    assign c = $signed(a_signed)*$signed(b);

    initial begin
        a = +5;
        b = +10;
        #(clk_period*1);
        $display("Hex: a=%x,b=%x, c=%x; Dec: a=%d, b=%d, c=%d", a, b, c, a, $signed(b), $signed(c));

        a = +5;
        b = -10;
        #(clk_period*1);
        $display("Hex: a=%x,b=%x, c=%x; Dec: a=%d, b=%d, c=%d", a, b, c, a, $signed(b), $signed(c));

        a = +255;
        b = +10;
        #(clk_period*1);
        $display("Hex: a=%x,b=%x, c=%x; Dec: a=%d, b=%d, c=%d", a, b, c, a, $signed(b), $signed(c));

        a = +255;
        b = -10;
        #(clk_period*1);
        $display("Hex: a=%x,b=%x, c=%x; Dec: a=%d, b=%d, c=%d", a, b, c, a, $signed(b), $signed(c));

        $stop;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

system verilog rules say

> If any operand is unsigned, the result is unsigned, regardless of the operator
>
> Propagate the type and size of the expression (or self-determined subexpression) back down to the context-determined operands of the expression
>
> When propagation reaches a simple operand as defined in 11.5, then that operand shall be converted to the propagated type and size.

So, in other words, when you multily signed and unsigned numbers, the expression type will be determined as `unsigned`. This will be propagated back to operands and all signed will be treated as unsigned as well.

so, your result will be identical to the one of multiplying two unsigned numbers. So, the cleanest way, if you need signed result, is to convert all operands to signed number.

You will also need an extra bit in your operands to have a place for the sign bit. Otherwise 255 will be treated as `-1` in 8-bit sign conversion.

Comment: So it seems this basic method is the cleanest possible. Still I was hoping for something cleaner than declaring and assigning to a new temporary signal just to do an unsigned*signed multiply.

Comment: assign c = $signed({1'b0, a})*$signed(b);     // on one line